# Can someone explain the steps of manipulation of this equation for the value of x?

Tags: linear-algebra

1. $x = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} 5j + 7$
2. $x = \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 5j + 7 \right) - 7$
3. $x = \left(5\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}7 \right) - 7$
4. $x = \left(5\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j + 7n \right) - 7$
5. $x = \frac{5n^2}{2} + 7n - 7$

I follow steps 1 to 3.

I understand that $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}$ is equal to $\frac{n^2}{2}$ in steps 4-5 but I don't understand the following:

How does $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}$ translate to $n$ in step 4 and what happens to $j$?

---

Update:
I believe that step 5 should be $x = \frac{5n(n-1)}2 + 7n - 7 = \frac 52 n^2 + \frac 92 n -7.$

Comment: Are you sure step 5 is correct?

Comment: Well, it's correct in that it's the solution I've been shown to understand.

Comment: You should write 5*(n-1)*n/2 for it to be correct.

Comment: Beacause as it stands you don't get an integer as the sum for any odd n, yet you are summing integers.

Answer (score 2):

4: What do you get if you do $7+7+...+7+7~~ n$ times? $~~7n!$

(from $0 $ to $ n-1$ there are n steps.)

For step 5 you have to write: $$x = \frac{5n^2-5n}{2} + 7n - 7$$
as$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j-n=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}-n=\frac{n^2+n-2n}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Think of the sum like this:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 7 = 7 \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}1 = 7(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n \text{ terms}}) = 7n$$

As for the $j$, that's just an index of summation, only present to take the values $0,\ 1,\ \cdots ,\ n-1$. Such an index should never survive the summation!